Meshes overlapping with sin() and cos() animation
I'm new to JavaScript and Three.js, nice to meet all of you !
This code is for creating 4 cubes and one arrow. Like this image:
Image1
// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Groups
const cubes = new THREE.Group();

// Ambient Light
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
scene.add(light)

// Reference Circle or Path
const circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5, 100)
const circlePath = new THREE.Path()
const stroke = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color : 'white'})
const ref = new THREE.Line(circle, stroke)
scene.add(ref)

// Mesh 
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'red' })
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)

// Mesh 2  
const geometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
const material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'blue' })
const mesh2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry2, material2)

// // Mesh 3 
const geometry3 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
const material3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'green' })
const mesh3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry3, material3)

// // Mesh 4 
const geometry4 = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
const material4 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'purple' })
const mesh4 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry4, material4)

// Mesh 5 Arrow
const geometry5 = new THREE.ConeGeometry(1, 4, 3)
const material5 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'yellow' })
const arrow = new THREE.Mesh(geometry5, material5)

scene.add(mesh, mesh2, mesh3, mesh4, arrow)


const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper();
scene.add(axesHelper)

// Camera

const aspect = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect.width / aspect.height)
camera.position.x = -0.15;
camera.position.z = 10;

scene.add(camera)

// Renderer 
const canvas = document.querySelector('.draw')
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
renderer.setSize(aspect.width, aspect.height)
renderer.render(scene, camera)

const clock = new THREE.Clock();

const animate = () => {
    const time = clock.getElapsedTime()
    console.log(time);
    const a = time;
    let px;
    let pz;
    let r = 5;

    px = r * Math.cos(a);
    pz = r * Math.sin(a);

    mesh.position.set(px, pz, 0);
    mesh.rotation.x = time * Math.PI * 0.1;
    mesh.rotation.y = time * Math.PI * 0.3;

    mesh2.position.set(px, pz, 0);
    mesh2.rotation.x = time * Math.PI * 0.1;
    mesh2.rotation.y = time * Math.PI * 0.3;
    
    mesh3.position.set(px2, pz, 0);
    mesh3.rotation.x = time * Math.PI * 0.1;
    mesh3.rotation.y = time * Math.PI * 0.3;

    mesh4.position.set(px, pz, 0);
    mesh4.rotation.x = time * Math.PI * 0.1;
    mesh4.rotation.y = time * Math.PI * 0.3;

    arrow.rotation.y = time * Math.PI * 0.7;

    renderer.render(scene, camera)
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
animate();

The problem I'm having is that when the animate() loop starts, I have all my geometry overlapped like this:
Image2
Do you have any suggestions on what could solve the overlapping ? Like doing some kind of delay maybe, not sure how to apply it.
What I understood was to create 4 loops for each cube. May be possible I'm not understanding correctly because when the program is running, I get: Image1.
Any suggestions on what could be done to make a delay for each mesh to avoid overlapping ?
Thanks for your time. :)

Have you tried running the code in your driver and stepping line by line through it? How to debug small programs StackOverflow is a question-and-answer site for specific questions about actual code; “I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix” is not a question, it’s a story, and not even an interesting story. I would also reduce it to a [mcve]. Why do you need 4 or 5 objects instead of two?

I've removed the AI part from your question. It has no value and is rather distracting.

All objects have the same position and rotation. Why do you expect them to not overlap? px2 is not defined. What is it? Where does it come from? Is it a typo? Why do you have two variables a and time for the same value?

I've fixed your code:

I've fixed the typo with px2.
I've moved every object on the circle with r * Math.cos(time + Math.PI / 2 * idx) and r * Math.sin(time + Math.PI / 2 * idx).
I've removed unnecessary variables.
I've added arrays and loops to reduce code duplication.

All objects had the same position and rotation.
// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Ambient Light
const light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 1);
scene.add(light);

// Reference Circle or Path
const circle = new THREE.CircleGeometry(5, 100);
const stroke = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color : 'white'});
const ref = new THREE.Line(circle, stroke);
scene.add(ref);

// Meshes
const meshes = [
    new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'red' })),
    new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'blue' })),
    new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'green' })),
    new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'purple' })),
];
const arrow = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.ConeGeometry(1, 4, 3), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'yellow' }));
scene.add(...meshes, arrow);


const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper();
scene.add(axesHelper);

// Camera

const aspect = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
};

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspect.width / aspect.height);
camera.position.x = -0.15;
camera.position.z = 10;

scene.add(camera);

// Renderer 
const canvas = document.querySelector('.draw');
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas });
renderer.setSize(aspect.width, aspect.height);
renderer.render(scene, camera);

const clock = new THREE.Clock();

const animate = () => {
    const time = clock.getElapsedTime();
    console.log(time);
    let r = 5;

    meshes.forEach((mesh, idx) => {
        mesh.position.set(r * Math.cos(time + Math.PI / 2 * idx), r * Math.sin(time + Math.PI / 2 * idx), 0);
        mesh.rotation.x = time * Math.PI * 0.1;
        mesh.rotation.y = time * Math.PI * 0.3;
    });
    arrow.rotation.y = time * Math.PI * 0.7;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate();


Hey thanks for the reply, this solved my problem!
Just have a few questions on some parts of your updated code:


When you create the meshes (the cubes) these are added with 'scene.add(...meshes, arrow) what does the three dots stand for ? Because I tried removing these and the code failed to add the cubes.


The loop for the meshes. I do not understand what does 'idx' stands for, where does this variable come from ? Is this a way of adding a 'delay' for each cube or what is happening ?



@user27057540 The three dots are spread syntax and idx is the second parameter (index) of the callback function of Array.prototype.forEach. No, that's not a delay.

@user27057540 It's r * sin(time + Math.PI / 2 * idx) and r * cos(time + Math.PI / 2 * idx) with idx in [0, 1, 2, 3]
